# Почему psycopg2 execute SELECT возвращает None, a SQL SELECT выдает результат?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, psycopg2

Запускаю класс

```
 class Botdb():
  def __init__(self, id_user = None, id_elected_user = None,
               id_status = None):
    self.id_elected_user = id_elected_user
    self.id_user = id_user
    self.id_status = id_status

  def selectData(self):
    with psycopg2.connect(
      database="...",
      user=LOGIN_DB,
      password=PASSWORD_DB
      )  as conn:
      with conn.cursor() as cur:
        response_select =  cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM elected_users;""")

        print("333", response_select)
        conn.rollback()

    return
```

Результат `None`

Если SQL

```
SELECT * FROM elected_users
```

отправить через софт, получаю нужную строку

Почему psycopg2 execute SELECT возвращает None, a SQL SELECT выдает результат?

Comment: Почитайте доку как использовать psycopg2 https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#basic-module-usage. execute сам по себе ничего не возвращает, а только выполняет запрос. Вам нужно вызвать один из методов fetchone/fetchall

Comment: Спасибо. 
Вопрос закрыт